# Java Postgres JDBC connection error org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail.Please report this

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, gradle, jdbc, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to my AWS postgres database in Android, but when I am trying to establish the connection I get the following error: **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.**

The driver I have is  **implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'**

The PostgresSQL version I have is **13.4**. I can connect to the AWS database from pgAdmin or IntelliJ database management. All credentials work on these apps. Security groups is set to **all connections and PostresSQL** for IPv4 and IPv6

The exception is triggered at conn = DriverManager.getConnection...

```
try {
    // TODO: Establish database connection
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://<endpoint from AWS>:5432/bank1?user=postgres&password=<password>");

    // Prepare the SQL statement to retrieve user details
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, username);
    stmt.setString(2, password);

    // Execute the query
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        // User authenticated, create a LoggedInUser instance
        String userId = rs.getString("id");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        LoggedInUser loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser(userId, name);
        return new Result.Success<>(loggedInUser);
    } else {
        // Invalid credentials
        return new Result.Error(new IOException("Invalid username or password"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    Log.getStackTraceString(e);
    return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
} finally {
    // Close the database resources
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

ext {
    qrgeneratorVersion = qrgeneratorVersion
}
android {
    namespace 'com.example.androidqrpayment'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidqrpayment"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}
```

[image: Full error]